# IE11 prompts authentication window on XML HttpRequest

Tags: javascript, iis, xmlhttprequest

I am running into an issue. The exact same request responds with 401 when sent from IE11.

The endpoint to which a request is sent is a WCF service for uploading a file.
I should probably mention that cookies are not an issue here.

The following is the code that is making the request:

```
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', upload.file);
                formData.append('secure_id', getCookieValue("SecureID"));

                var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

                oReq.open("POST", this.fileUploadUrl, true);

                var self = this;
                oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
                    if (oReq.status == 200) {
                        upload.status = self.$root.uploadStatusEnum.DONE;
                        upload.message = self.$root.humanFileSize(upload.file.size);
                        self.refreshData(true);
                    } else {
                        upload.status = self.$root.uploadStatusEnum.ERROR;
                        upload.message = "Upload Error";
                    }
                    
                    self.processUploads(uploads.slice(0, uploads.length - 1));
                };
                oReq.send(formData);
```

IE11 left, Chrome right.

[image: Request intercept through Fiddler. IE11 on the left. Chrome on the right]

I tried the following things to no avail:

- Changing XMLHttpRequest to ActiveXObject
- Disabling windows authentication in IIS

Comment: Could you please share how you are uploading the file? please share a reproducible example if possible. which authentication you are using ntml or Negotiate? did you enable anonymous authentication in iis? try to set Internet explorer->internet option->security->click local intranet -> Custom level ->Enable Prompt for user name and password to have Internet Explorer prompt for credentials. Enable Automatic logon with current user name and password to have Internet Explorer automatically log in as the currently logged on Windows user.restart ie.https://imgur.com/a/kWV3A8T

Comment: check iis log for sub status code.